# Cambiar valores del data desde un file.js externo

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Debido al gran volumen de líneas que presenta mi script en vue, lo he movido a un fichero js externo para tenerlo todo más organizado y limpio.

Pero se me ha presentado un problema. La aplicación tiene una loading page para ir mostrando al principio el estado de carga de la aplicación, y esta tiene que ir mostrando que se va cargando en un texto. El valor se va cambiando desde el **padre.js**, y no se como hace para que los cambios se vayan reflejando en el componente **loadingPage.vue**.

La estructura sería algo así:

```
Estructura:
*padre.vue
*padre.js
*loadingPage(folder):
    *loadingPage.vue
```

En padre.js:

```
export default {
  loadedElement: null,

  loadContent: function(){
    this.loadFirstElement();
    setTimeOut(()=>{this.loadSecondElement();},3000);
  },

  loadFirstElement: function(){
    this.loadElement = "Primer elemento cargado";
  },

  loadSecondelement: function(){
    this.loadElement = "Segundo elemento cargado";
  }
}
```

En el padre.vue:

```
<template>
  <loadingPage :prop_loadedElement="loadedElement"/>
</template>
<script>
  import loadingPage from "../loadingPage/loadingPage";
  import padre from "./padre.js";
  export default {  
    name: "padre",
    data(){
      return {
        loadedElement: null
      }
    },
    components: {
      loadingPage
    },
  }
</script>
```

Y finalmente, en el loadingPage.vue, se recogería esa prop y se mostraría en el DOM e iría cambiando.

Por supuesto esto no es la estructura original de mi proyecto, es un ejemplo básico para explicar lo que quiero hacer. 
Lo que hice en un primer momento fue pasar toda la lógica del fichero vue al js, mediante el mounted del padre.vue:

```
mounted: function(){
    padre.vueLogic = this;
}
```

De esta manera podría acceder al loadedElement de padre.vue desde padre.js, pero no sé si es adecuado. Lo único que tendría que hacer con esto sería en el js:

```
vueLogic.loadedElement = "Primer elemento cargado";
...
vueLogic.loadedElement = "Segundo elemento cargado";
```